# How can I handle onchange for a select option in WebSharper UI.Next

Tags: f#, single-page-application, websharper, websharper.ui.next

I am trying to display a different SPA view based on the option selected from Doc.Select.

I would like to handle onchange events using WebSharper UI.Next. I have searched around for some information and have seen `on` which can be set in the attributes of an `Elt`, like so:

`spanAttr [on.click (fun el ev -> ())] [text "some span"]`

found here: http://www.websharper.com/question/81410/event-handlers-for-ui-next-elt-objects

However, I am quite unsure of how to handle a change on `Doc.Select` using the tools available in UI.Next.

I have the following:

```
let rv = Var.Create "1"
Doc.Select [  ] (fun _ -> "") [ "1"; "2"; "3" ] rv
```

I am not sure how to get access to onchange events so I can use the router to redirect to a different SPA view.

What is the convention for doing something like changing a view based on the dropdown selection?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to handle `onchange` yourself. If you use `Doc.Select` the corresponding `Var` will be updated every time the dropdown changes. You can just do something like:

```
rv.View.Doc(function
    | "1" -> text "page 1"
    | "2" -> text "page 2"
    | "3" -> text "page 3"
    | _ -> failwith "Should never happen")
```

and embed that into your main `Doc` that gets rendered.